# How to atmospherically correct Landsat 8 data?

Tags: remote-sensing, erdas-imagine, landsat, landsat-8, atmospheric-correction

What is a simple way to atmospherically correct Landsat 8 data using Erdas 9.3 or ArcGIS 9.3?

Comment: Most of the data available from Landsat has already been corrected to some degree. See the documents here: http://landsat.usgs.gov/documents/provisional_l8sr_product_guide.pdf

Comment: do you have atcor in Erdas ?

Comment: No  I have no atcor in erdas @ radouxju

Answer (score 1):

I would advise using the dark object subtraction (DOS) method for atmospheric correction. Essentially, you find a dark object in your scene--such as a deep, dark water body--where you know there is no reflectance.  Any brightness values associated with the dark object in your scene are therefore likely the result of atmospheric effects. These values can then be subtracted from the other pixel values.

Resources:

1. [Classification and Change Detection Using Landsat TM Data: When and
   How to Correct Atmospheric Effects?](http://www.unc.edu/courses/2007spring/geog/577/001/www/Song01_RSE.pdf).
2. [DOS in Erdas Imagine (Youtube)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9ED3jnYod6w)